# Find missing letter in list of alphabets

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the following issue:

Find the missing letter in the passed letter range and return it. If all letters are present in the range, return undefined.

the inputs that I will get as strings are:

- abce (Which should return d)
- bcd (which should return undefined)
- abcdefghjklmno (which should return i)
- yz (which should return undefined)

my code currently looks like this:

```
  function fearNotLetter(str) {
  //create alphabet string
  //find starting letter in alphabet str, using str
  //compare letters sequentially
  //if the sequence doesn't match at one point then return letter
  //if all letters in str appear then return undefined

  var alphabet = ("abcdefgheijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  while (i<alphabet.length && j<str.length) {
    i++;
    if (alphabet.charCodeAt(i) === str.charCodeAt(j)) {
      i++;
      j++;      
    }
    else if (alphabet.charCodeAt(i) !== str.charCodeAt(j)) {
      i++;
      j++;
      if (alphabet.charCodeAt(i) === str.charCodeAt(j-1)) {
        return alphabet.charCodeAt(i-1);  
      }
    }
  }
}

fearNotLetter('abce');
```

Thanks for your help as always!

Comment: What's the problem with your code as-is? You should state a specific error or problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
    var i, j = 0, m = 122;
    if (str) {
        i = str.charCodeAt(0);
        while (i <= m && j < str.length) {
            if (String.fromCharCode(i) !== str.charAt(j)) {
                return String.fromCharCode(i);
            }
            i++; j++;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

console.log(fearNotLetter('abce'));        // "d"
console.log(fearNotLetter('bcd'));         // undefined
console.log(fearNotLetter('bcdefh'));      // "g"
console.log(fearNotLetter(''));            // undefined
console.log(fearNotLetter('abcde'));       // undefined
console.log(fearNotLetter('abcdefghjkl')); // "i"
```

`i` can go from 97 to 122, this interval corresponds to the [ASCII codes of the lower case alphabet](http://www.asciitable.com/).

If you want it not to be case sensitive, just do `str = str.toLowerCase()` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: We seem to find the same questions interesting, although we often take very different approaches.  I think I prefer your solution.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Yeah, I've seen you before :) It'll return `a`? I'm getting `undefined` in the test cases I added to my code.

Comment: Thanks for this and all the other answers. But this might be the one I understood the easiest (well after some time analyzing it). How would you make it work for capital letters? Would you just change the value of m?

Answer (score 8):

I think this is the simplest code to do this:

```js
function skippedLetter(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charCodeAt(i + 1) - str.charCodeAt(i) != 1) {
            return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1);
        }
    }
}

alert(skippedLetter('abce'));
```

This version will reject illegal input, accept both upper and lower case, check that there is only 1 hole in the range, and that there is exactly 1 character missing.

```js
function skippedLetter(str) {
    if (!str.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) return;
    var letter = "", offset = str.charCodeAt(0);
    for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        var diff = str.charCodeAt(i) - i - offset;
        if (diff == 1) letter += String.fromCharCode(i + offset++)
        else if (diff) return;
    }
    if (letter.length == 1) return letter;
}

alert(skippedLetter('123567'));  // illegal characters
alert(skippedLetter(''));  // empty string
alert(skippedLetter('a'));  // too short
alert(skippedLetter('bc'));  // nothing missing
alert(skippedLetter('df'));  // skipped letter = e
alert(skippedLetter('GHIKLM'));  // skipped letter = J
alert(skippedLetter('nOpRsT'));  // cases mixed
alert(skippedLetter('nopxyz'));  // too many characters missing
alert(skippedLetter('abcefgijk')); // character missing more than once
alert(skippedLetter('abcefgfe')); // out of order
```

Comment: Thanks @m69 I will analyze your solution, but can see why RegEx might be a better answer here to capture both lower and upperCase.

Comment: Just to be clear, the simple version also works for upper and lower case. However, it assumes that the input will always be "legal", i.e. either of the form "nopqrst" or "noprst", and will return the first character that's missing. This will of course let through "illegal" input like "nopxyz" or "noppon" or "nop$£€", all of which will return "q". If you know the input will always be "legal", the short version will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have a typo in `alphabet`:  There are two "e"s.

You could **[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** the string into an array, then use the **[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** method to short-circuit the loop when you don't find a match:

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
      missing,
      i= 0;
  
  str.split('').some(function(l1) {
    var l2= alphabet.substr(i++, 1);
    if(l1 !== l2) {
      if(i===1) missing= undefined;
      else      missing= l2;
      return true;
    }
  });
  
  return missing;
}

console.log(fearNotLetter('abce'));             //d
console.log(fearNotLetter('bcd'));              //undefined
console.log(fearNotLetter('abcdefghjklmno'));   //i
console.log(fearNotLetter('yz'));               //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Another function that may help:

```
var alphabet = "abcdefgheijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
function fearNotLetter(a) {
  function letterIndex(text, index) {
    var letter = text.charAt(0);
    if (alphabet.indexOf(letter) !== index) { return alphabet.charAt(index); } else { return letterIndex(text.substring(1), index + 1) }
  }
  if (alphabet.indexOf(a) === -1) {
    return letterIndex(a, alphabet.indexOf(a.charAt(0)));
  }
  return undefined;
}
fearNotLetter("abc"); //Undefined
fearNotLetter("abce"); //d
fearNotLetter("fgi"); //h
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're looking for:

Hit run and check your console

```js
function missingLetter (str) {
    var alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    var first = alphabet.indexOf(str[0]);
    var strIndex = 0;
    var missing;

    for (var i = first ; i < str.length ; i++) {
        if (str[strIndex] === alphabet[i]) {
            strIndex++;
        } else {
            missing = alphabet[i];
        }
    }
    return missing;
}

console.log(missingLetter("abce"));
console.log(missingLetter("bcd"));
console.log(missingLetter("abcdefghjklmno"));
console.log(missingLetter("yz"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wanted to say that if a string doesn't start with "a" than return "undefined". So here's my code:

```js
 function fearNotLetter(str) {
   var alphabet = ("abcdefgheijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
   var i = 0;
   var j = 0;
   while (i < alphabet.length && j < str.length) {
     if (alphabet.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j)) {
       i++;
       j++;
       if (alphabet.charAt(i - 1) == "a") {
         return "undefined";
       } else {
         return (alphabet.charAt(i - 1));
       }
     }
     i++;
     j++;
   }
 }

 alert(fearNotLetter('abce'));
```

Here's the working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiureznicencu/rus6gbr4/).

You wanted the code to return the missing letter so I used CharAt.
You can make an array of letters and then search through it to see if it maches with letters from the string....

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {

  var a = str.split('');
  var array = [];
  var j = 0;

  for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    var d = a[i].charCodeAt(0);
    var c = a[i - 1].charCodeAt(0);

    var delta = d - c;

    if (delta != 1) {
      array[i] = String.fromCharCode(a[i - 1].charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    }
  }

  str = array.join('');

  if (str.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    return str;
  }
}

fearNotLetter('abcefr');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? it finds all missing letters anywhere between the first and the last given letters:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var strArr = str.split('');
  var missingChars = [], i = 0;
  var nextChar = String.fromCharCode(strArr[i].charCodeAt(0)+1);
  while (i<strArr.length - 1) {
    if (nextChar !== strArr[i+1]){
      missingChars.push(nextChar);
      nextChar = String.fromCharCode(nextChar.charCodeAt(0)+1);
    } else {
      i++;
      nextChar = String.fromCharCode(strArr[i].charCodeAt(0)+1);
    }
  }

  return missingChars.join('') === '' ? undefined : missingChars.join('') ;
}

console.log(fearNotLetter("ab"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an even shorter answer thanks to `RegExp()` that allows you to create a Regular Expression on the fly and use `match()` to strip off the given letters from a generated String that has all the letters in the given range:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var allChars = '';
  var notChars = new RegExp('[^'+str+']','g');
  for (var i=0;allChars[allChars.length-1] !== str[str.length-1] ;i++)
    allChars += String.fromCharCode(str[0].charCodeAt(0)+i);
  return allChars.match(notChars) ? allChars.match(notChars).join('') : undefined;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
        var firstLtrUnicode = str.charCodeAt(0),
            lastLtrUnicode = str.charCodeAt(str.length - 1);
        var holder = [];
        for (var i=firstLtrUnicode; i<=lastLtrUnicode; i++) {
            holder.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
        }
        var finalStr = holder.join('');
        if ( finalStr === str ) { return undefined; }
        else { return holder.filter( function(letter) {
            return str.split('').indexOf(letter) === -1;
        }).join(''); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
    var alp = ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ').split(''), i;
    for (i =  alp.indexOf(str.charAt(0)); i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.split('').indexOf(alp[i]) === -1) {
            return alp[i];
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

fearNotLetter('bcd');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, which i find to be quite easy to interpret:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var missingLetter;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) - str.charCodeAt(i-1) > 1) {
      missingLetter = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) - 1);
    }
  }
  return missingLetter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this challenge. I am a beginner to Javascript so this was my approach, very simple, sometimes you don't have to use the methods they provide but they also help. I hope you can understand it.

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {

var alphabet= "abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var piece =alphabet.slice(0, str.length+1);




for(var i=0; i < piece.length; i++ ){
if(str.charCodeAt(0) != 97){

return undefined;
}

else if(str.indexOf(piece[i])===-1){
  return piece[i];
}
}// for loop

}

fearNotLetter("abce");// It will return d
fearNotLetter("xy");//It will return undefined
fearNotLetter("bce");//It will return undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function fearNotLetter(str) {
  //transform the string to an array of characters    
  str = str.split('');

  //generate an array of letters from a to z
  var lettersArr = genCharArray('a', 'z');
  //transform the array of letters to string
  lettersArr = lettersArr.join('');
  //substr the a to z string starting from the first letter of the provided 
  string
  lettersArr = lettersArr.substr(lettersArr.indexOf(str[0]), str.length);
  //transform it again to an array of letters
  lettersArr = lettersArr.split('');
  //compare the provided str to the array of letters
  for(var i=0; i<lettersArr.length;i++){
    if(str[i] !== lettersArr[i])
      return lettersArr[i];
  }
  return undefined;
}

function genCharArray(charA, charZ) {
    var a = [], i = charA.charCodeAt(0), j = charZ.charCodeAt(0);
    for (; i <= j; ++i) {
        a.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
    }
    return a;
}

fearNotLetter("bcd");
```

Comment: Some explanations about this piece of code would probably be beneficial.

Comment: I've added some comments to explain who the code works, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's my another answer in missing letters:

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  var first = alphabet.indexOf(str[0]);
  var last = alphabet.indexOf(str[str.length-1]);
  var alpha = alphabet.slice(first,last);

  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    if(str[i] !== alpha[i]){
      return alpha[i];
    }
  } 
}

console.log(fearNotLetter("abce"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Overview:

```
 const fearNotLetter = str => {
  if(str.length < 26) {
    return String.fromCharCode( 
      str.split("")
      .map(x=> x.charCodeAt(0))
      .sort((a,b) => a-b)
      .find((x,i,a) => a[i+1]-x > 1) + 1
    );
  }
}
```

1 liner:

```
const fearNotLetter = str => str.length < 26 ? String.fromCharCode(str.split("").map(x=> x.charCodeAt(0)).sort((a,b) => a-b).find((x,i,a) => a[i+1]-x > 1) + 1) : undefined;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
var allChars = "";
var notChars = new RegExp("[^" + str + "]","g");

for (var i = 0; allChars[allChars.length - 1] !== str[str.length - 1]; i++)
allChars += String.fromCharCode(str[0].charCodeAt(0) + i);

return allChars.match(notChars) ? allChars.match(notChars).join("") : undefined;
}
```

Comment: You will need to explain why your answer is correct

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  let startingPoint = alphabet.indexOf(str[0]);
  let leaterNotMatch = alphabet.slice(startingPoint)
  console.log(startingPoint)
  for(let i = 0; i<str.length; i +=1){
    if(str[i] != leaterNotMatch[i]){
      return leaterNotMatch[i];
    }
  }
}

let result = fearNotLetter("abcdefghjklmno");
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function findMissingLetter(letters) {
   const alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
    'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
    'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

   let otherAlphabet = [];

   if (letters[0] !== letters[0].toUpperCase()) {
     otherAlphabet = alphabet.map(item => item.toLowerCase());
   } else {
     otherAlphabet = alphabet;
   }

   const firstIndex = otherAlphabet.findIndex((aplhabetEl) => {
     return aplhabetEl === letters[0];
   });

   const lastIndex = otherAlphabet.findIndex((aplhabetEl) => {
     return aplhabetEl === letters[letters.length - 1];
   });

   const sliceAlphabet = otherAlphabet.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex + 1);

   let result = '';

   for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
     if (letters[i] !== sliceAlphabet[i]) {
       result += sliceAlphabet[I];
     }
   }

   return result.slice(0, 1);
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this question by using a map which we will call `seen`. For every letter, we will add it to our `seen` map. Then we will loop through the `alphabet` checking if we have come across that letter in our `seen` map.

If we have come across that letter in our `seen` map, then we will use a boolean flag `foundFirstLetter` and set that to true. Then inside another conditional `foundFirstLetter`, we can check if the letter is missing and if it is we can just return the letter because we know it's missing.

This solution works, but it isn't ideal because it uses more *space* (because of our seen map), unlike the other solutions.

```
const findMissingLetter = (array) => {
  const convertUpperCase = array[0] === array[0].toUpperCase() ? true : false;
  const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const seen = {};
  let foundFirstLetter = false;
  
  // add the words we have run across to our seen map
  for(const letter of array){
    seen[letter.toLowerCase()] = true;
  }
  
  // loop through our alphabet checking if letter is in our map. If we find the first letter, then that means
  // if we don't find the next letter in our map then it's missing.
  for(const letter of alphabet){
    
    if(seen.hasOwnProperty(letter)){
      foundFirstLetter = true;  
    }
    
    if(foundFirstLetter){
      if(!seen.hasOwnProperty(letter)){
        if(convertUpperCase){
          return letter.toUpperCase();
        } else {
          return letter;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {  
  var string = array. join("");
  for (var i = 0; i < string. length; i++) {                    
    if (string. charCodeAt(i + 1) - string. charCodeAt(i) != 1) {
      return String. fromCharCode(string. charCodeAt(i) + 1);
    } 
  }
  return undefined 
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26406562)

Comment: Please make the code work. It uses undefined variables. What is `array.join("")` doing? Also consider using the code snipet tool.